# Update in child table, only one value got updated

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, t-sql, olap

Below I am trying to update value of a parent table from child table and counting matching values. Tables in my db:

1. `issue_dimension` with id = issue_id and have column accno.
2. `star_schema` with id star_id,this Child column have fk issue_id and column book_frequency

The book_frequency need to match the count of each accno in parent table , I tried this

```
update [test1] .[dbo] .star_schema 
set [book_frequency] = (
    select top 1 COUNT([issue_dimension].ACCNO)as book_frequency 
    from issue_dimension 
    group by ACCNO having (COUNT(*)>1) and 
        issue_dimension.ACCNO = star_schema .ACCNO
)
```

It only updates only 1st value count issue_dimension. I need to count every accno in issue_dimension and update it to matching accno of star_schema.
I never did update by joining two or more tables , can anyone help in this with joins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE s
SET [book_frequency] = i.CNT
FROM [test1].[dbo].star_schema s
    INNER JOIN 
    ( 
        SELECT ACCNO, COUNT(*) as CNT
        FROM issue_dimension 
        GROUP BY ACC_NO
        HAVING COUNT(*)>1
    ) i on (s.ACCNO = i.ACCNO)
```

I didn't check it but it should works

Comment: it again updating  only one value , its counting only one value

Comment: how many rows returns: `SELECT ACCNO, COUNT(*) as CNT FROM issue_dimension GROUP BY ACC_NO HAVING COUNT(*)>1`?

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way, without grouping, just with the `WHERE` clause:

```
UPDATE [test1].[dbo].star_schema SET 
    [book_frequency] =
        ( 
            SELECT COUNT([issue_dimension].ACCNO)
            FROM issue_dimension 
            WHERE issue_dimension .ACCNO = star_schema.ACCNO  
            HAVING COUNT(*)>1
        )
```

Comment: hmmm , buts still updating one result

Comment: will it solve with joins ? I never used joins in update statement

Comment: You can use joins in update, but I think that not GROUP BY, So, may be you again should strip off the HAVING COUNT(*)>1?

Answer (score 0):

It's not fully clear to me so the answer is a bit of guessing:

```
update s set
    book_frequency = t.qty
from star_schema s
join issue_dimension i on s.issue_id = s.issue_id
join (select count(*) as qty, accno 
    from issue_dimension
    group by accno
) t on i.accno = t.accno
```

Comment: here is unnecessary join to issue_dimension :)

Comment: @chopikadze: in question, exactly in part describing tables there is no info about column `accno` in table `star_schema`. The only connection I've noticed is `issue_dimension.issue_id (id, probably PK) = star_schema.issue_id (FK)`. That's why I've used it to join them.

Comment: but example query from the question contains :) well, anyway, both of our answers are very close and should allows questionier to find right solution I think :)

Comment: @chopikadze: ...and that's why I don't like badly asked questions :-).

Comment: there is an int value say 't' in both tables .in table one , 't' count is called in other table against every matching value of 't' in other table

Comment: @user1074474: please add to the question sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the example from BOL that does the kind of thing you're looking for, using AW:

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO
UPDATE Sales.SalesPerson
SET SalesYTD = SalesYTD + 
    (SELECT SUM(so.SubTotal) 
     FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS so
     WHERE so.OrderDate = (SELECT MAX(OrderDate)
                           FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS so2
                           WHERE so2.SalesPersonID = so.SalesPersonID)
     AND Sales.SalesPerson.BusinessEntityID = so.SalesPersonID
     GROUP BY so.SalesPersonID);
```